# MATLAB: Split large array into smaller arrays, and plotting them as part of the same series

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, series, scatter, large-data

## Problem

Running out of memory when running the scatter plot function with large arrays as inputs (**6.7E6 elements**).

#### Approach

I have two large sets of data in cells with size **(n x 1)**.

```
xCell = cell(n,1);
yCell = cell(n,1);
```

The data inside of the cells are multiple arrays of variable size (**VariableSize x 1**). I concatenate all of the arrays from each cell into one array each.

```
% Combine cells into one array
x = cat(1,xCell{:});
y = cat(1,yCell{:});
% Clear unnecessary variables
clear xCell yCell
```

I end up with two arrays **x** and **y** with the same size (**6.7E6 elements**) ready as inputs for a scatter plot. After executing my code, I end up with a memory error.

#### Output

```
??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

I have maxed out the amount of heap space available for my computer and I have nothing else running on the computer.

## Objective

I would like to load only parts (sub-arrays) of the data at a time while creating the scatter plot and conserving the fact that the smaller sub-arrays are all part of only one larger series.

Comment: Use the `whos` command on your variables to see how large they are. You can also use the `memory` command to see how much memory is available to matlab.  A few million elements shouldn't be that taxing, so the above steps may help you figure out if something is much larger than you think it is.

Comment: Ah. I just remembered... the performance of `scatter` can be truly abysmal, especially with large numbers of points. Try using `plot(x,y,'.')` instead.

Comment: Arr the elements of type `double`? If u have integer values u could change to other type, e.g. `int16`.

Comment: Going into the plot, I only have those two arrays. I will try using the plot(x,y,'.') command to see if it behaves better than **scatter(x,y)**. @Marcin I will check to see if I can reduce the size of the data type to something else that is not 64 bits. Thanks to both of you for such a quick response.

Answer (score 3):

you can use tools such as [cloudPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23238-cloudplot) and [plot(Big)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40790-plot-big) from the FEX. **cloudPlot** will help visualize the distribution of a 2-dimensional dataset. It is especially helpful when looking at extremely large datasets where a regular `plot(x,y,'.')` will just fill the plot with a solid color because the measurement points overlap each other.  **plot(Big)** intercepts data going into a plot and reduces it to the smallest possible set that looks identical given the number of pixels available on the screen. It then updates the data as a user zooms or pans. This is useful when a user must plot a very large amount of data and explore it visually.

See more [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2013/10/25/visualizing-the-frequency-distribution-of-2-dimensional-data/) on how to visualize distributions of 2d data.